# PHP JSON How to subtract date and time

Tags: php, json

I have php code which I extracted a date from a json request. The json time data prints as

2017-07-01T07:32:57Z

Can you provide 2 examples:

Example 1 how to subtract time by 1 day

Example 2 php if statement.

```
if(current time IS 60 Minutes > than JSON time and date){
  echo "time is great than 60 minutes";
}
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, welcome to SO. Please take a moment and look into this to improve your question(s): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subtract date by 1 day,  replace your date in `$your_date_time`

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($your_date_time)))
```

to check if time is greater than 60 minutes

```
if(strtotime($your_date_time) > strtotime("-60 minutes")) {
    echo "time is great than 60 minutes";
}
```

hope this helps